# yEd to MySQL Workbench

Tags: entity-relationship, mysql-workbench

yEd is a modeling software tool that is for free.  I really enjoy using this modeling software tool because of its simplicity and quick deployment.

During my work i will take a break here and there and just kind of dream up some of my side projects entity relationship in yEd.  So after building something over some course of time i wanted to transfer it to mysql.

After several searches i cannot find anything that is related to mysql workbench and yEd.  Is there a way to import a yEd model into mysql workbench?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yEd produces XML files that are pretty easy to understand. I've eventually managed to build some XSLT files that are capable of reading source yEd files and transform them to any output I need. (I was producing pipelines similar to those used in XProc standards)

My developpements in this field were very specific to my needs, but it's an easy task as long as you now some XML/XSLT basics.

Don't hesitate to ask further questions if you need help for this.

Comment: +1.  Its a good idea, i do not have the time for such things though :(.  At this time i have moved away from MySQL workbench due to its limitations in the EER Models.  Namely when you rename a column in the model it drops all the data and creates a new column instead of a simple alter table statement... :(

Answer (score -1):

I developed a script that converts a TGF file to SQL.

URL: https://tioconejo.alwaysdata.net/prototipos/tgf2sql/

You just draw your diagram using YED, save it as TGF, copy the content in the site, and it will parse and transform it into SQL.

You have to draw the diagram following some criteria. It works fine!

[The diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygHSv.png)
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II8ez.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).